# Do I need to install SQL Server & SQL Server Management Studio, after installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssms, visual-studio-2015

Recently I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition on my computer. I found that there are some components/features missing (e.g. SQL Server & SQL Server Management Studio) like they were installed automatically with previous Visual Studio versions (i.e. Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate).

Although I installed the Enterprise version but didn't find any such SQL Server product installed on my computer. Previously these were installed with Ultimate version automatically. And from this link (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx) I found that these should be installed with it & the old Ultimate version is now Enterprise version.

Do I need to install SQL Server & SQL Server Management Studio, after installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server - yes, you need to install it. If you want to use the full SQL Server Management Studio - yes, you have to install it, too. You can use the vastly improved "SQL Server Object Explorer" in VS 2013 and 2015 and you might be able to get by without installing the full Management Studio

Comment: this is really silly why VS doesn't have basic management capabilities as SSMS anyway its based on VS2010 shell. we have to shell out 1+ gb space on SSDs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server is a separate product and you need to install it before or after you install Visual Studio 2015 Professional/Enterprise.

What you get from Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Enterprise is tooling that support working with SQL Server not the actual product it self.

Comment: But they were auto installed with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir: VS 2013 used to install SQL Server **Express** - and a lot of folks complained about that, so Microsoft changed it - now other folks are complaining about that, too ..... damned if you do, damned if you don't .... If you need SQL Server - **just install it** and get on with your life ! .....